# Manually set JDK path in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, overriding, java

I'm trying to install Eclipse, Android SDK, JDK6 and JRE6 to one of the computers in my school. I have limited access to it so I can't run any installators or modify the program files folder. I have installed everything on my home computer and transferred the files to the other computer by using memory stick. Eclipse, Android SDK and JRE6 work really well and I was able to set Eclipse to use their file paths. How should I install JDK6, as it should be installed to program files and found automatically by Eclipse? I can't find any setting for it.

Some of my @Override functions give the error "must override a superclass method", which apparently is because of the default JDK5, but how can I set Eclipse to use the version 6 instead? My JRE is set to use the version 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per my suggestion, it is not good to remove that line. you need to change to JDK version in your eclipse then you will not get such errors. Follow, following steps for it,

Right Click on your Project & select Properties.

Then from the left section Select Java Compiler & select the Version of the JDK you installed. If it is already selected then de-select it & try it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886744/how-install-multiple-jdk-on-windows I was able to find the JDK with JRE browser, which confused me a bit.

The rest of the problem required Project->Properties->Java Compiler->Confiqure Workspace Settings and set the Compiler compliance level to 1.6.

Comment: My problem was, that I didn't find anywhere to set my JDK path. With that solution I linked, I noticed that I had to set it as JRE with Preferences->Java->Compiler->Installed JREs and then set the JRE in the Installed JREs->Execution Environment.

Comment: There was one JDK there. I'm not sure if it was in the file systems of my school, but I didn't install it.