# How to import java.nio.file package

Tags: file, import, nio, java

Im trying to listen to a directory for changes, then discovered java.nio.* was developed to handle efficiently such tasks and more. Then downloaded jdk1.7.0_02 from oracle and started eclipse with it. Then created new java project, tryed to implement some class from java.nio.file and Oh my eyes! "The import java.nio.file cannot be resolved".
Do i have to find some .jar in the whole jdk1.7.0_02 directory that contains such package? or is something wrong with my classpath?
 Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've different version of [JDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886744/how-install-multiple-jdk-on-windows). You just need to set `JDK7/JRE7` version  eclipse project. You may also select the `Execution environment JRE` to JavaSE 7 while creating a new project.

The JDK your projects use to compile, the version of the resulting class files, the JRE they used to execute and the JDK eclipse runs with are widely independent settings.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked like a charm. Just defined the compliance level to 1.7 instead of 1.6

Comment: `java.nio` has been available since Java 1.4 released in 2000, you don't have to have java 7 to use it.

Comment: But he/she wants to import `java.nio.file` package.

Comment: i have a Dynamic Web Project, just edited the .classpath file to match this
`<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.7.0_05">`

Comment: please explain how will i do that bcoz m using eclipse .. while creating project it cant be ask or no option of Execution environment JRE..

Answer (score 1):

The New I/0 is named as the NIO in javaSE 7.0 ("Dolphin").

The below link described as in details.

[wiki - NIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O#NIO_buffers)

Comment: use JDK version "jdk1.8.0_25". This will resolve the NIO issue