# No java.nio.file in JDK8

Tags: java, java-8, java.nio.file

I have JDK 8 installed and the compiler won't import `nio.file`. I'm using Windows 7 64's cmd.exe. Everywhere on the Internet people have this problem because they have JDK 6 or earlier, I have JDK 8 so I have no idea what's going on. `import java.nio.*;` works fine but it still doesn't have the classes I need. I just keep getting

```
cannot find symbol
import java.nio.file;
               ^
```

EDIT: As I said I don't use an IDE, just notepad + cmd.exe. `javac -version` results in `javac 1.8.0`.

Comment: Do a `javac -version` and show us the result if you are compiling from the command line. Otherwise check your IDE compilation compliance level.

Comment: Also, is that literally your `import` statement? `file` is not a type name, nor a member name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338586/how-to-import-java-nio-file-package

Comment: use an IDE for your sake and ours, there are plenty of free ones Intellij IDEA is the best as far as I am concerned. They all would tell you what was wrong and how to fix it, you are wasting your time and ours with fundamental questions like this!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `import` statement is used so that you don't have to use fully qualified names of types in your source code. You use the `import` statement with type names or their members.

`java.nio.file` does not identify a type. It is a package.

You need

```
import java.nio.file.*;
```

to import all types in that package or some specific type

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
```

(among other possibilities depending on your requirements and preferences.)